# Rails 5 concat two atributes to show as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this method as a source for an autocomplete text field.

```
def index

@articulos = Articulo.where("descripcion ILIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')",params[:term]).
or(Articulo.where("codigo ILIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')",params[:term]))
render json: @articulos.map(&:descripcion)

end
```

This query searches by description or Codigo but JSON shows in the autocomplete field just the description. I need that the JSON shows the Codigo attribute and description concatenated in the autocomplete text field, e.g.

```
34432 - descripcion del articulo
```

Comment: how about `.select("(codigo || '-' || descripcion) as descripcion")`?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla this works fine, but i lost the rest of the fields like price or id. I want to select all attributes but only show codigo -descripcion. any idea?

Comment: Try with `.select("*,(codigo || '-' || descripcion) as descripcion")`, if this doesn't work, please let me know the database you use.

Comment: But thinking about, maybe you need to chance the `as descripcion` to something else, like `as representation` to avoid problems with the actual descripcion field.

Comment: ok, y add * and fields like price and timestamps are showed correctly but integers fields (id, created_by) are not showed, im using postgres

Comment: This works on my postgrest db (removing the parenthesis) `.select("*, codigo || '-' || descripcion AS respresentacion")`, let my know if work for you.